# How to avoid Multiple Async Thread calls?

Tags: android

friends,

i am using following code to fill android listview asynchronously

now problem is while running this thread i press back button or home button and comes back to activity

multiple threads are started....

can i avoid these multiple threads
actually i want if thread is running then it should not get called again and again.
it should be called when previous thread is complete.

```
private static String[] items={.......};

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setListAdapter(
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                new ArrayList()));

        AddStringTask test= new AddStringTask();
        test.execute();




    }


class AddStringTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            for (String item : items) {
                publishProgress(item);
                SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            }

            return(null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... item) {
            ((ArrayAdapter)getListAdapter()).add(item[0]);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            Toast
                .makeText(AsyncThread.this, 
                        "Done - Finished updating Java Book List!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

        }
    }
}
```

any useful solution?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to animate the addition of List items? Coz if you are, there are better ways to do this...

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the `Activity` Closing by overriding `onStop()` or `onPause()` or even `onBackPressed()` and terminate the update when it does...

If you don't wish to terminate it and instead just want NOT to initiate it again, just use static variables (or any other method) such that the `test` variable is created only once...

To terminate a `AsyncTask`, i believe there's a `cancel()` method...Use `true` as its parameter.

From API Reference

```
final boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)
//Attempts to cancel execution of this task.
```